# html5 css3 creating audio sound from text

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create an audible sound from text?

So that one can play a page although one have no knowledge about the spelling?

So that we can use a tag like below:

```
<read gender="woman">Read Me in the voice of a robotic woman</read>
```

Comment: Look at this: http://ctrlq.org/code/19147-text-to-speech-php. I dont think you can perform text to speech in html (including html 5)

Comment: Also what I would do personally is get a free text to speech application which can be found online. Then record the words and save the speech in an audio file. Upload the audio file to your server and have html play the file when a button is pressed. This however, can only be done for static content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just a few audio files you can create it with speech text program (be careful about copyrights) and then play it in client-side..

but if you need encompass solution, and create a lot of audio speech files,  you need to buy something like this

http://www.wizzardsoftware.com/att_server_overview.php

it's create the sound file in your server side only, and then you need play it in the client side